# Rails 4 - Passing a variable from custom validator for localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a i18n file as:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      messages:
        email_address: "%{email} is not a valid email"
```

And I have a custom validator for e-mail:

```
class EmailFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each record, attribute, value
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || :email_address) unless
    value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/
  end
end
```

How can I pass value of `%{email}` from above validator to i18n yml file? I keep getting this error:

```
missing interpolation argument :email in "%{email} is not a valid email" ({:model=>"Signup", :attribute=>"Email", :value=>"sdsdfsdf"} given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message the translated `model` name, translated `attribute` name, and `value` are always available for interpolation.

As you can see also in the exception message:

> missing interpolation argument :email in "%{email} is not a valid email" (**{:model=>"Signup", :attribute=>"Email", :value=>"sdsdfsdf"}** given)

So you need to use `%{value}` to get the actual value `"sdsdfsdf"` in the error message:

```
email_address: "%{value} is not a valid email"
```

This will display: `Email sdsdfsdf is not a valid email`. However if you want to change how **all** the error messages are formatted, you can do it under the `errors.format` key in the localization:

```
en:
  errors:
    # The default format to use in full error messages. "%{attribute} %{message}"
    format: "%{message}"
```

Comment: thanks. I quickly figured out that right after posting this question. But I get this string `Email sdsdfsdf is not a valid email` where you can see this string starts with `Email` which I don't want and that is not even the part of string in yml. I want string should be `sdsdfsdf is not a valid email`

Comment: @JVK I've updated my answer with a way how you can change the error message formatting for the whole application. You cannot do this only for one attribute see in [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L370-L379).

Comment: Thanks @nemesv I got it and selected your answer. Unfortunately, this will affect all error messages in the validation, so I may have to compromise and let my error msg looks like that only :(